# programmatically create phabricator diff request without any repo

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

I am trying to simulate creating diff request without actually creating the repo, diff and doing arc diff.

I want to use the 
https://secure.phabricator.com/conduit/method/differential.createrawdiff/

or the createDiff command. But I am not sure what should the json be ?
How is the diff request sent over ? How do I fake create that to be used with the curl request ?

Any insights and help is greatly appreciated ?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

This was the json I used:

```
'{
    "diff": "diff --git a/scripts/deploy/restart_apache b/scripts/deploy/restart_apache\nindex 510a7f9..d29177c 100755\n--- a/scripts/deploy/restart_apache\n+++ b/scripts/deploy/restart_apache\n@@ -59,7 +59,7 @@ do\n                                         # Set variables for the alpha context.\n                                         webServerBaseName='\''alpha-w'\''\n                                         webServerSuffix='\'''\''\n-                                        numWebServers=1\n+                                        numWebServers=2\n                                         checkPort=80\n                                         ;;\n                                 \"beta\")"
}'
```

You will, however, need to use Arcanist.  I do not believe there is a way to use the API without using Arcanist.  Yo don't need to use `arc diff` but you will still need Arcanist.  The command you would use through Arcanist is this:

```
echo $json_string | arc call-conduit --conduit-uri https://secure.phabricator.com/ --conduit-token $conduit_token differential.createrawdiff
```